# ffmpeg save hls to m3u8 with mp4 segments

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, m3u8

I am looking for a command ffmpeg, which saving live input (rtmp or hls) to hls m3u8 with mp4 segments files. I know that it is possible to do, i.e. there is infohttps://bitmovin.com/hls-news-wwdc-2016/ but every command I tries - makes ts files. Anyone know solution?

Comment: Use the segment [muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment).

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -re \
  -i http://inputfile.m3u8 \
  -c:v copy \
  -c:a copy \
  -hls_time 10 \
  -hls_list_size 3 \
  -hls_wrap 3 \
  -hls_segment_type fmp4 \
  /location/to/file/index.m3u8
```